# Removing the cigar lighter socket in the Outback load area

Tags: electrical, subaru, trim

I want to use the cigar lighter socket in the load area of my 2022 Subaru Outback to charge a LiFePO2 battery. I understand that these circuits should be limited to 10A (although the Subaru has a 20A fuse for this circuit) and I have a charger which will limit the current to 10A.

Unfortunately **I am getting a lot of voltage drop across the socket** -- I see 9V at the charger when it draws 10A. The positive terminal of the cigar lighter plug gets very hot.

**So I want to remove the cigar lighter socket and replace it with an Anderson connector**.

I don't know how to get the cigar lighter socket out of the trim. As you can see in the photo, there's a hatch which allows me to reach the socket from above, **but I don't understand how it's retained**. (off topic: what's that purple thing with "K" on it? The plastic cord seems to head towards the fuel filler.)
[image: The access hatch and the socket]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I slipped a bit of plastic between the socket and the trim, to protect the trim, and then just levered against the socket and the plastic with a screwdriver. It didn't take much force, and nothing snapped.

(now I see that the wire diameter is 1.75mm, including insulation, and looking in the fuse box it's fused for 20A. That seems like a big fuse for what is presumably AWG 14 *at best* so some of my voltage drop is probably just in the wire, but that's another question)

Answer (score 2):

The K tab may be a mechanical release when the solenoid release fails to unlock the fuel access cover. Your owner's manual should have info or try Subaru's website. As to power socket removal, try using a small mechanics mirror and light to see inside that access hole. You should be able to determine how to remove the outlet. Be sure to remove the fuse and measure the socket for power before removing it.